# Get HTML from existing instance of Internet Explorer from Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, internet-explorer, mshtml, twebbrowser

On a specific website, If I open a new instance of IE, I'm already authenticated, as long as there at the same time is another open instance of IE where I previously have logged in. 
If I open a tWebbrowser from Delphi, I'm not authenticated. 
Since I don't want to log in in every single tWebbrowser I create, I want to find a way how to keep this authentiation that works fine, when I manually open new instances of IE. 
The purpose is the get the HTML from different pages where I'm logged in.

I want either

1) Get the HTML from an instance of Internet Explorer opened with ShellExecute

or

2) Have tWebbrowser to remember the authentication from all the other open instances of IE

or

3) connect a tWebbrowser to an existing instance of internet explorer

or

4) some other way to get the HTML from Delphi

The authentication I can't find out how to automatize since it is java/sso.

Comment: If the user can authenticate in their browser, why can't they do it in your browser?

Comment: yes, it is possible to authenticate in my tWebbrowser, but since I want to make an automation program with a lot of tWebbrowsers, it would difficult to log-in so many times.

Comment: Do you need a web browser? Do you need to render the html? Why don't you get the credentials from the user, store them, and use something like Indy to get the HTML?

Comment: The log-in process is using username and password and then the java applet is showing a number, which you have to look up in a table at a sheet of paper and then type into the applet. It takes almost 1 minute on my windows xp machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the Windows shell for IE windows by doing something like this:

```
uses ShDocVw_Tlb; // or ShDocVw

if Doc = Nil then
  exit;
if Doc.body = Nil then
  exit;

var
  i: Integer;
  Browser: IWebBrowser2;
  ShellWindows: IShellWindows;
  Doc : IHtmlDocument2;

ShellWindows := CoShellWindows.Create;
for i := 0 to ShellWindows.Count - 1 do
  if Supports(ShellWindows.Item(i), IWebBrowser2, Browser) then 
  begin
    // do something with Browser instance, e.g compare the Url you're
    // expecting with Browser.LocationUrl
    // if it is, then you can get at the Html by something like

    Browser.Document.QueryInterface(IHtmlDocument2, Doc);
    if (Doc <> Nil) and (Doc.Body <> Nil) then  
    // access any of the Doc's properties, e.g. InnerHtml

  end;
```

Obviously, when Support returns true, you can examine the returned browser for what you're looking for.  E.g. you can use the `IHtmlDocument2` interface of the browser's Document (check that it's not Nil first) to access its DOM, HTML, etc.  I imagine it's relatively straightforward to find a `TWebBrowser` window instead, if that's what you're wanting to do.

Comment: There is no ShDocVw_Tlb in Delphi. unless you explicitly imported ShDocVw. and your code shows I have 2 IWebBrowser2 even if I never opened IE.

Comment: "your code shows I have 2 IWebBrowser2" Well, that doesn't necessarily mean that they're coming from IE, does it?

Comment: I realize that (not sure were they coming from thought). Again, You should mention that in your answer. just trying to improve your answer :)

Comment: "your code shows I have 2 IWebBrowser2"  Well,a) he can check the returned Browser's url to see if it's the one he's looking for and b) in practice I've found this method more reliable than trying to query IE when there are several instances (according to TaskMan) of IE running.

Comment: ->MartynA
Your code works fine as far as I can see. 
When I use Browser.Navigate(...) then it opens a new instance of IE. It's ok, since the authentication still is working. But how can I check if the page is fully loaded? Usually I use Ondocumentcomplete, but when I don't have a tWebbrowser, I don't know how to do it. I have tried to use Browser.Busy=false but I don't know if it is always working. 
How can I check the url of one of the existing instances?

Comment: @Peter, you can compare the Url you're expecting with the LocationUrl property of the Browser instance. If it is, you should be able to get all you need from the existing Browser instance, without calling .Navigate on it.

Comment: By the way, do you know how I close the browser instance again?